# How can I return None or throw an exception if no implicit defined?

Tags: scala

I have this function:

```
case object Evaluator {
    import Ordering.Implicits._
    def eval[T: Ordering](x: T, y: T): Boolean = Some(x < y)
}
```

I want that in case that the use sends unsupported object to the eval function to return None. 
e.g.:

```
case object Bar
assert(Evaluator.eval(Bar, 1) == None)
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try providing the default value for the implicit argument.

```
case object Evaluator{
    import Ordering.Implicits._
    def eval[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit ev:Ordering[T] = null):Boolan =
      if(ev == null)
        None 
      else
        Some(x < y)
}
```